# Can't capture telnet.exe output with Win32 ReadConsoleOutput()

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

Can anyone explain why I'm finding it impossible to capture the output of telnet.exe with the Windows function ReadConsoleOutput?

I'm calling it via C# interop . 
The class I'm using is below.

```
  public static class ConsoleReader
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> ReadFromBuffer(short x, short y, short width, short height)
    {
        IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(width * height * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CHAR_INFO)));
        if (buffer == null)
            throw new OutOfMemoryException();

        try
        {
            COORD coord = new COORD();
            SMALL_RECT rc = new SMALL_RECT();
            rc.Left = x;
            rc.Top = y;
            rc.Right = (short)(x + width - 1);
            rc.Bottom = (short)(y + height - 1);

            COORD size = new COORD();
            size.X = width;
            size.Y = height;

            const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;
            if (!ReadConsoleOutput(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), buffer, size, coord, ref rc))
            {
                // 'Not enough storage is available to process this command' may be raised for buffer size > 64K (see ReadConsoleOutput doc.)
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }

            IntPtr ptr = buffer;
            for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
                {
                    CHAR_INFO ci = (CHAR_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(CHAR_INFO));
                    char[] chars = Console.OutputEncoding.GetChars(ci.charData);
                    sb.Append(chars[0]);
                    ptr += Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CHAR_INFO));
                }
                yield return sb.ToString();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct CHAR_INFO
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
        public byte[] charData;
        public short attributes;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct COORD
    {
        public short X;
        public short Y;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct SMALL_RECT
    {
        public short Left;
        public short Top;
        public short Right;
        public short Bottom;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO
    {
        public COORD dwSize;
        public COORD dwCursorPosition;
        public short wAttributes;
        public SMALL_RECT srWindow;
        public COORD dwMaximumWindowSize;
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool ReadConsoleOutput(IntPtr hConsoleOutput, IntPtr lpBuffer, COORD dwBufferSize, COORD dwBufferCoord, ref SMALL_RECT lpReadRegion);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);
}
```

Demo:

```
        Process p = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName = @"telnet";
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;

        p.StartInfo = psi;
        p.Start();

        while (true) 
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            string[] consoleContent = ConsoleReader.ReadFromBuffer(0, 0, 150, 100).ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: Because telnet doesn't write to standard out. It can redirect its output to a file by using the `-f` argument: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787407(v=WS.10).aspx  I'm not sure if /f accepts `con` as a file.

Comment: Do you know where it writes and how I might capture its output?
As a last resort I may end up hacking together the right Windows events to select all and copy to clipboard or something whacky like that.

Comment: you can choose any file for the `-f` so `-fc:\temp\mylog.txt` could work...

Comment: I'm not trying to log the output of a session.
I need to be able to interact with the telnet application - by sending input which I can do by simulating keystrokes - and by reading it's output in real time.

Comment: Try it with `-fcon`  (or `-fcon:`) and use your current bits to see if that will fly.

Comment: No such luck
`The system cannot find the file specified`.
Thanks none the less.